# Why the load speed varies for a CodeIgniter empty page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm loading an empty page with `$this->output->enable_profiler(true)`.

When I first load the page, I get a controller execution time of 80ms (seems very slow for an empty screen). Then, if I refresh the page quickly the numbers get lower. Around 16ms for controller execution. However, if I wait a few seconds and reload the page, it's slow again.

What's going on here? There is some kind of caching? Is this normal? What numbers are other people getting?

I'm using CodeIgniter version 2.2.0.

Benchmarks for slow loading:

```
BENCHMARKS
Loading Time: Base Classes                    0.0014
Controller Execution Time ( Test / Phpinfo )  0.0880
Total Execution Time                          0.0897
```

Benchmarks for faster loading:

```
BENCHMARKS
Loading Time: Base Classes                    0.0013
Controller Execution Time ( Test / Phpinfo )  0.0160
Total Execution Time                          0.0175
```

Comment: for me it was caused by the autoloader, specially the database. apparently i have a database that's sometimes very slow to make a connection to. i debuged by putting prints throughout codeigniter core source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server environment, and how busy it is (how many processes are going on at any given millisecond) could affect how fast your page is generated. That said, it does seem like your server is especially slow, which could explain why you see a greater variance. I consider my dev server to be slow, and I get these kind of benchmarks:

```
Loading Time: Base Classes                   0.0008
Controller Execution Time ( Test / Index )   0.0002
Total Execution Time                         0.0010
```

For me, total execution time varies between 0.0008 and 0.0016. This kind of variance could be the result of system antivirus, or basically any other program or process doing something. Because PHP and your HTTP server are sharing system resources with everything else on the computer/server, you will see a variance, and that's normal.

If you're curious, you should look into the CPU and memory usage of your computer, and see how it varies, even when you think it is idle.

Comment: ty! seeing your numbers lets me know this isn't normal for codeigniter and i should investigate more